# Aspnet Third Party Auth and DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure

I am trying to make an ASP.NET MVC Azure-hosted website role that allows third-party authentication.

The client might not want me to add SQL server since it costs money, and I can cut back since all of my data comes from CRM. My problem is that **DotNetOpenAuth**, the library that supports the authentication, appears to require some database tables for storage. However I do not want to use any storage since I want to put all my data (and the auth token) in CRM.

**1)** If I don't use DB to persist the token, then is it a good idea to use encrypted cookie/server-side sessions? What do I have to modify?

**2)** Is in-memory, non-DB sessions from 1)* scalable in Azure?

**3)** Is there any way to make DotNetOpenAuth (WebSecurity class) work without relying on a db?

Answer (score 0):

DotnetOpenAuth doesn't require database, you provide your own implementations of few interfaces, nowhere db is required.

Tokens are not persisted. Instead, tokens contain username and scopes encrypted with a private key of the authentication server. This way all you need is the public key in the resource server to decrypt the token (the `ICryptoKeyStore` interface).

You could as well persist keys in the filesystem or elsewhere.